# What are snaps in ros2?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm into learning ros2 and I came by snaps.The documentation says Snaps bundle your application along with all the necessary dependencies! What does it mean in layman's language !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/405450/what-are-snaps-in-ros2?/) by [sidharth.jeyabal](https://answers.ros.org/users/53096/sidharth.jeyabal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2022-08-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-08-24**:
Snap is not a ROS thing. It's a Canonical / Ubuntu application packaging and deployment system.

Compare with Flatpak, AppImage and perhaps even Docker (if it's abused).

Canonical just figured out how to use the snap infrastructure and tools to package ROS applications.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is your good base tutorial about snap: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-your-first-snap#1-overview

> A snap is a bundle of an app and its
> dependencies that works without
> modification across many different
> Linux distributions. Snaps are
> discoverable and installable from the
> Snap Store (...)

It allows you to combine everything you need for "publishing" your software application with its dependencies (e.g. additional libraries, plugins etc.).

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-08-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sidharth.jeyabal](https://answers.ros.org/users/53096/sidharth.jeyabal/) on 2022-08-24**:
Thank you so much for the info i will read through it ..Have a good day

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! Good question. I work for Canonical, the publisher of Ubuntu. I’m part of the robotics team.  Snaps is one of the many tools we developed for developers to easily deploy and manage their applications.

**Snap offers you a way to deploy your ROS applications.** If you are familiar with Ubuntu, you probably already downloaded packages with APT. Well, Snap is an alternative way to share and download applications.

**Snap bundles all the necessary dependencies.** This means that the snap you download is all you need; it is self-contained. The snap package doesn't only contain your application, but all the libraries necessary to run it. This makes your software stable, and you can even deploy ROS 2 Humble applications on Ubuntu 18.04 for instance.

**Snaps are running in a confined environment.** Snaps are isolated from the host and only have access to what you explicitly gave access to. If you want your snap to access the network, you must declare it.

**Snaps and their updates can be shared easily on the Snapstore.** Snaps are updated automatically when an update is available. If you are a developer, you can upload the update, and it will deploy to your user/robots automatically.

These are only a few highlights,

If you are interested as a ROS snap user, you can give a shot at the [Plotjuggler](https://snapcraft.io/plotjuggler) or [Gazebo](https://snapcraft.io/gazebo).

If you are interested as a ROS developer to deploy your application, have a look at the [snapcraft quick-start documentation](https://snapcraft.io/docs/snapcraft-overview) as well as the [snapcraft robotics documentation](https://snapcraft.io/docs/robotics).

---

Originally posted by [GuillaumeB](https://answers.ros.org/users/19670/guillaumeb/) with karma: 312 on 2022-08-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sidharth.jeyabal](https://answers.ros.org/users/53096/sidharth.jeyabal/) on 2022-08-24**:
Thanks for the info im overwhelmed with the effort u took to answer!1

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-08-24**:
Really nice answer, I learned a lot